# React Native: justify flex items (child) separately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to have a button where the middle text is centered in the middle and an additional text is pushed to the right, like in this image:

```
https://i.imgur.com/oNDeFJo.png
```

I tried marginLeft property but react-native flexbox model behaves differently than css, this is my code:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{ flex:1, height:40, backgroundColor:'rgb(255,216,0)',  borderRadius:5 }}>
          <View style={{ flex:1, height:40, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', paddingHorizontal:20 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black' }}>Add to cart</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black', marginLeft:'auto' }}>19:00</Text>
          </View> 
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{ height:40, backgroundColor:'rgb(255,216,0)',  borderRadius:5 }}>
          <View style={{ height:40, flexDirection:'row', paddingHorizontal:20; width: 100%;}}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black', flex:2; text-align: center; }}>Add to cart</Text> 
            <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black', flex:1; text-align: right}}>19:00</Text>
          </View> 
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This ratio is 2:1, you can even change it to 3:1 according to the need.
For this, just change flex:3 from first `<Text/>`.

Adjust flex value according to your requirement.

For the web version, you can verify this using the following code snippet:

```html
<div class="box" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
  <div style="flex:2; text-align: center;">One</div>
  <div style="flex:1; text-align: right">Two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add absolute position so both texts are individual.
in addition it will always let the main text align to the center.

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{ flex:1, height:40, backgroundColor:'rgb(255,216,0)',  borderRadius:5 }}>
          <View style={{ flex:1, height:40, flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', paddingHorizontal:20 }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black' }}>Add to cart</Text> 
          </View> 
          <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 3, height: 40, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize:16, color:'black', marginLeft:'auto' }}>19:00</Text>
          </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```